# Pass pointer by value where it is supposed to be passed by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am learning C++

I have a function:

```
void remove_node(node *&rem);
```

As I understood, `rem` is a `node*`, which is passed by reference. I do need it to be passed by reference, because I change the pointer.

But sometimes I need to pass it by value (recursive call). I did it like this:

```
node *noref = rem->left;
remove_node(noref);
```

instead of

```
remove_node(rem->left);
```

Is there better way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You're not passing by value. You're passing a copy of the pointer `rem->left` by reference.

Comment: Ehm, if you are removing a node, surely you need to update the pointer to that node, so SHOULD pass `rem->left` and not a copy thereof? If you "need" to pass a copy for some reason, then your `remove_node` is broken, not the point which is calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you wish to do with your nodes ?
What are the attributs & methods of the class ?

Usually when using nodes, you just change the links between the nodes, and not the nodes themselves (ex : double-linked list).

```
struct node {
    node* right;
    node* left;
};
typedef struct node node;

void remove_node(node* n) {
    l_node = n->left;
    r_node = n->right;
    l_node->right = r_node;
    r_node->left = l_node;
    free(n);
}
```

that would be the C code, to pass it to C++ just use the accessors and the destructor :)

Comment: Actually, your class seems to not modify `n` at all, which, from what I read in the question, the OP's solution does...